# How to set qlabel text's opacity in PyQt?

Tags: html, css, pyqt, qlabel

I have a label and I want to set it html\css formatted text from `text` variable.

```
label = QtGui.QLabel()   
text = '''<font face="tahoma" color="#45688E">THIS TEXT</font>'''
label.setText(text)
```

I need the word **THIS** to be colored with my color(#45688E) and word **TEXT** to be transparent.

The idea is that I want label to show only one word on screen, meanwhile I could programatically get two words.

How to do it?

Thank you.

Update1: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvJhe.png)
Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.resize(300, 400)
window.setWindowTitle('TITLE1')

window_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(window_layout)

label = QtGui.QLabel()   
text = '''<font face="tahoma"><span style="color:#45688E">THIS</span><span style="opacity:0"> TEXTANOTHER_WORD</span></font>'''
label.setText(text)

window_layout.addWidget(label)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your first word in a span tag and style with a color. Add all other words in another span tag and set the opacity of the span tag to 0

```
'''<font face="tahoma"><span style="color:#45688E">THIS</span><span style="opacity:0">TEXTANOTHER_WORD</span></font>'''
```

Browser Snippet below

```html
<font face="tahoma"><span style="color:#45688E">THIS</span><span style="opacity:0">TEXTANOTHER_WORD</span></font>
```

EDIT:

**Solution 2**

```
 '''<font face="tahoma"><span style="color:#45688E">THIS</span><span style="display:none">TEXTANOTHER_WORD</span></font>'''
```

**A somewhat odd solution with PyQT**

Somewhat setting the color to transparent hides that text

```
style="color:transparent"
```

Example

```
text = '''<font face="tahoma" color="red" style="color:green;"><span>THIS</span><span  style="color:transparent">TEXT</span></font>'''
```

Picture below

[image: see picture here]

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated my question with photo and code. It seems that Qt does not fully support html\css formatting (opacity for example)

Comment: try style="display:none" for the hidden container

Comment: sorry, hidden what?

Comment: check solution 2 in my answer

Comment: Last but not least, I suggest you replace that <font> with <div>. Also check what verison og PyQT you are using css works fine in webkit on my Pyqt

Comment: Nope. No changes. PyQt 4.7

Comment: Okay..I found a way setting the color to transparent. Picture also attached

Comment: GREAT!!!! Thank you so much. People, who are ready to help a stranger, the best!!